# Neo4j ruby gem intro screencast

Tags: neo4j

I am trying to follow the screen cast and replicate the blog example presented here: https://github.com/neo4jrb/neo4j/tree/master/example/blog

First command executed, first error, Run time Error, please see below and advise how to proceed correctly:
`` rails new blog -m http://neo4jrb.github.com/neo4j/neo4j.rb –0
     create

     create  README.rdoc
     create  Rakefile
     create  config.ru
     create  .gitignore
     create  Gemfile
     create  app
...
     create  tmp/cache
     create  tmp/cache/assets
     create  vendor/assets/javascripts
     create  vendor/assets/javascripts/.keep
     create  vendor/assets/stylesheets
     create  vendor/assets/stylesheets/.keep
      apply  http://neo4jrb.github.com/neo4j/neo4j.rb
/Users/liviu-mac/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/open-uri.rb:231:in `open_loop': HTTP redirection loop: http://neo4jrb.io/neo4j/neo4j.rb (RuntimeError)
    from /Users/liviu-mac/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/open-uri.rb:149:in `open_uri'
    from /Users/liviu-mac/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/open-uri.rb:704:in `open'
    from /Users/liviu-mac/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/open-uri.rb:34:in `open'
    from /Users/liviu-mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/actions.rb:218:in `apply'
    from /Users/liviu-mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/generators/app_base.rb:144:in `apply_rails_template' ``

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bDjbqRL9HcM, you should see an overlay on the screen at the 1:25 mark with the new, fixed address:

```
rails new blog -m http://neo4jrb.io/neo4j/neo4j.rb -O
```

It's in the videos notes, too. The old one broke when we put the new site online.

Comment: Sorry, my fault, I used another source for the video https://showyou.com/v/y-bDjbqRL9HcM/neo4j-ruby-gem-intro-screencast The you tube link has the right info, the new command executed without errors. Thank you.